# “E: Unable to locate package python3-pip” in Debian 10

Tags: python-3.x, pip, debian

For installing pip3, I am following apt update process.
But I am getting the following output in the terminal:

Command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pip
```

I tried all available solutions on Stack Overflow. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the *sources.list* file is not configured properly, so if none of solutions work then try this:
Type in the terminal: `gedit etc/apt/sources.list`.

A file will open. Check if these given lines are present or not in that file:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

In my case these were missing. This means the *apt-get* command didn't have any mirrors configured to pull and update packages. These lines are the links to Debian repositories from where packages are pulled.
Copy and paste these lines into that file and save and close it.

Now run `sudo apt-get update` and than run `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Once the process finishes, run `sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip`. This will install pip3 without any error.

Answer (score 1):

Please run an update and upgrade,

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Hopefully, this will fix the issue. If this doesn't work, you can always update the source list manually.

Comment: Thanks, I had to do update the source list manually.